# Proof that given $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n!$ divides $(p^n - 1)(p^n - p)\cdots(p^n - p^{n-1})$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, symmetric-groups, general-linear-group

I was hoping to show this by Lagrange's theorem.
As the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (the field with $p$ elements), $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb F_p)$ has order $(p^n - 1)(p^n - p)\cdots(p^n - p^{n-1})$, we just need to find a subgroup that has an order of $n!$.

We know that $S_n$ ([symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)) has order $n!$ and since it is isomorphic to the set of permutation matrices with matrix multiplication as its operation, we already have or proof constructed.

My problem here is that it works for every $p \in \mathbb{N}$, it is not required for $p$ to be prime. Where am I wrong? Am I wrong?

Comment: When $p$ is not prime, you have no $\mathbb{F}_p$, and the analogue of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has the order not that easy to compute.

Comment: You can prove the fact you are after by counting the number of unordered bases in a vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$; I take it you absolutely want to do it using Lagrange?

Comment: On a slightly related note, the nice paper [The General Linear Group Over a Ring](http://koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO200634741588239.page) by Juncheol Han indicates ways to compute the order of $GL_n(R)$, when $R$ is any finite, unital ring, commutative or not. It is more complicated than when $R$ is a finite field.

Answer (score 1):

It only works for $p$ prime, because otherwise you don't have a vector space over the field $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: Why is that? It isn't so intuitive for me.

Comment: Fields all have prime power order.  In particular, $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field.  If you're trying to talk about general linear groups over rings $\Bbb Z_n$ it's different.  Modules over rings are generalizations of vector spaces over fields.